# How to calculate time amount of time that line above trend line in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering how I could calculate the amount of time that data is above a trend line. The code look like this at the moment.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

csv = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data = csv[['time', 'amount']]
x = data['time']
y = data['amount']

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo-')

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r--")

plt.show()
```

The CSV file is this

```
time,amount
10,5
9,5.5
8,5
7,6.3
6,6
5,4
```

And the graph shows this at the moment

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j6j6.jpg

I kind of want to have something like this that the graph shows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcmni.jpg

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy masks can be used to restrict curves to where some condition holds. The condition is only calculated at the values of the arrays, so in order to avoid gaps, a dense array can be used:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(data=[[10, 5], [9, 5.5], [8, 5], [7, 6.3], [6, 6], [5, 4]], columns=['time', 'amount'])
data = data.sort_values(['time'])
x = np.array(data['time'])
y = np.array(data['amount'])

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo-')

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)

x_dense = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 500)
y_dense = np.interp(x_dense, x, y)

mask = y_dense < p(x_dense)
x_masked = np.ma.array(x_dense, mask=mask)

plt.plot(x_dense, p(x_dense), "r-", lw=0.2)
plt.plot(x_masked, p(x_masked), "r--")
plt.fill_between(x_dense, p(x_dense), y_dense, where=~mask, color='crimson', alpha=.3)

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]